# How to pass a mask without a plug-in through a input value in Vue.js?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify.js

By now, I did the function with pure JavaScript, but now I don't know how to apply in vue.js, either which lifecycle hook are proper for this. I'm a beginner, so this is for a test to a first job and I'm stuck on this.

The challenge is to pass a telephone mask through the input, like this (xx)xxxxx-xxxx. Also the challenge is to make everything in one single HTML file. I'm using Vue.js v2.x and Vuetify.

This is how the input are currently working **:**

```
<v-text-field
  id="phone"
  onkeypress="mask(this, mphone)"
  onblur="mask(this, mphone)"
  v-model="numero"
  maxlength="15"
  label="Número com DDD"
  :rules="rulesNum"
  required
>
</v-text-field>
```

And this is the functions **:**

```
function mask(object) {
          setTimeout(function() {
              var valueInput = mphone(object.value);
              if (valueInput != object.value) {
                object.value = valueInput;
              }
            }, 1);
          }

      function  mphone(valueInput) {
            var regex = valueInput.replace(/\D/g, "");
            regex = regex.replace(/^0/, "");
            if (regex.length > 10) {
              regex = regex.replace(/^(\d\d)(\d{5})(\d{4}).*/, "($1) $2-$3");
            } else if (regex.length > 5) {
              regex = regex.replace(/^(\d\d)(\d{4})(\d{0,4}).*/, "($1) $2-$3");
            } else if (regex.length > 2) {
              regex = regex.replace(/(\d)(\d{4})$/,"$1-$2");
            } else {
              regex = regex.replace(/^(\d*)/, "($1");
            }
            return regex;
          }
```

Comment: It's unclear for me. What do you mean by *pass a telephone mask through the input* ? For ex : If user enter his telephone number `(91) 99999-99999` you have to convert that into `(XX) XXXXX-XXXXX`  ? If Yes, you have to do that conversion while submitting the form or while typing itself ?

Answer (score 0):

If you're just trying to refactor these functions to a vue structure what you need is, on the html element transform onkeypress and onblur to @keypress and @blur. After that just take your functions and put them inside the methods from the vue structure like so:

```
methods: {
    mask: function(object) {
        //your code
    },
    mphone: function(valueInput) {
        //your code
    }
}
```